# How to parse multiple XML files

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I am trying to parse multiple XML files with Nokogiri. They are in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CRDoc>[Congressional Record Volume<volume>141</volume>, Number<number>213</number>(<weekday>Sunday</weekday>,<month>December</month>
  <day>31</day>,<year>1995</year>)]
[<chamber>Senate</chamber>]
[Page<pages>S19323</pages>]<congress>104</congress>
  <session>1</session>
  <document_title>UNANIMOUS-CONSENT REQUEST--HOUSE MESSAGE ON S. 1508</document_title>
  <speaker name="Mr. DASCHLE">Mr. DASCHLE</speaker>.<speaking name="Mr. DASCHLE">Mr. President, I said this on the floor yesterday 
afternoon, and I will repeat it this afternoon. I know that the 
distinguished majority leader wants an agreement as much as I do, and I 
do not hold him personally responsible for the fact that we are not 
able to overcome this impasse. I commend him for his efforts at trying 
to do so again today.</speaking>
  <speaking name="Mr. DASCHLE">Let me try one other option. We have already been unable to agree to 
a continuing resolution that would have put all Federal employees back 
to work with pay. We have been unable to agree to something that we 
agreed to last Friday, the 22d of December, which would have at least 
sent them back to their offices without pay. Perhaps we can try this.</speaking>
  <speaking name="Mr. DASCHLE">I ask unanimous consent that the Senate proceed to the message from 
the House on S. 1508, that the Senate concur in the House amendment 
with a substitute amendment that includes the text of Senator Dole's 
back-to-work bill, and the House-passed expedited procedures shall take 
effect only if the budget agreement does not cut Medicare more than 
necessary to ensure the solvency of the Medicare part A trust fund and, 
second, does not raise taxes on working Americans, does not cut funding 
for education or environmental enforcement, and maintains the 
individual health guarantee under Medicaid and, third, provides that 
any tax reductions in the budget agreement go only to Americans making 
under $100,000; that the motion to concur be agreed to, and the motion 
to reconsider be laid upon the table.</speaking>
  <speaker name="The ACTING PRESIDENT pro tempore">The ACTING PRESIDENT pro tempore</speaker>.<speaking name="The ACTING PRESIDENT pro tempore">Is there objection?</speaking>
  <speaker name="Mr. DOLE">Mr. DOLE</speaker>.<speaking name="Mr. DOLE">Mr. President, I want to say a few words. But I will 
object.</speaking>
  <speaking name="Mr. DOLE">We are working on a lot of these things in our meetings at the White 
House, where we have both been for a number of hours. I think we have 
made some progress. We are a long way from any solution yet.</speaking>
  <speaking name="Mr. DOLE">I think all of the things listed by the Democratic leader are areas 
of concern in the meetings we have had. And the meetings will start 
again on Tuesday. But it seems to me that it would not be appropriate 
to proceed under those terms, and therefore I object.</speaking>
  <speaker name="The ACTING PRESIDENT pro tempore">The ACTING PRESIDENT pro tempore</speaker>.<speaking name="The ACTING PRESIDENT pro tempore">Objection is heard.</speaking>
</CRDoc>
```

The code I am using came from previous help and has worked a treat so far. However, the format of the XML files has changed and left the code unusable. The code I have is this:

```
doc.xpath("//speech/speaking/@name").map(&:text).uniq.each do |name|
  speaker = Nokogiri::XML('<root/>')
  doc.xpath('//speech').each do |speech|
    speech_node = Nokogiri::XML('<speech/>')
    speech.xpath("*[@name='#{name}']").each do |speaking|
      speech_node.root.add_child(speaking)
    end
    speaker.root.add_child(speech_node.root) unless speech_node.root.children.empty?
  end
  File.open("test/" + name + "-" + year + ".xml", 'a+') do |f|
    f.write speaker.root.children
  end
end
```

I would like to create a new XML file for each speaker and in each new XML file have what they said. The code needs to be able to cycle through the various XML files in a directory and place each speech in the appropriate speaker file. I was thinking this could be accomplished with a `find -exec` command.

Ultimately, the code should:

1. Create an XML file with the speakers name and year i.e., `Mr. Boehner_2011.xml`
2. The XML file will hold all of his speeches for that year.
3. The XML file will have a `CRDoc` root node.

Comment: There's no `<speech>` element. Simply change `//speech/speaking/@name` to `//speaking/@name`.

Comment: I tried that already it creates the files properly, but unfortunately they are empty.

Comment: Try the class in my solution below, it should retrieve everything.

Comment: Don't use `a+` to append to an XML file. That'll only result in invalid XML. Instead use `w` and rewrite the file. If you are trying to append you need to read the old file, then use Nokogiri to append the new information to the XML document, then rewrite it. XML isn't CSV.

Comment: When asking about code, we need the _minimum_ input data that demonstrates the problem. That means strip out everything that is not essential or is redundant. That helps us help you. Please read "[mcve]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have the `<speech>` element anymore, you need to remove it from your code:

```
doc.xpath("//speaking/@name").map(&:text).uniq.each do |name|
  speaker = Nokogiri::XML('<root/>')
  doc.xpath('//CRDoc').each do |speech|
    speech_node = Nokogiri::XML('<speech/>')
    speech.xpath("*[@name='#{name}']").each do |speaking|
      speech_node.root.add_child(speaking)
    end
    speaker.root.add_child(speech_node.root) unless speech_node.root.children.empty?
  end
  File.open("test/" + name + "-" + year + ".xml", 'a+') do |f|
    f.write speaker.root.children
  end
end
```

Comment: This code as always works a treat. I am going to try the above example posed, and the most functional will be the accepted answer. Do you have any recommended reading for your code so I am to better understand it?

Comment: Most of this code is simply using XPath, which you can read up on http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion is, rather than continuing to use code you don't understand, break it down into bits so that it is easier to understand, or at least it will be easier to isolate a problem.

Imagine being able to do this:

```
crdoc = CongressionalRecordDocument.new(filename)

crdoc.year
#=> 1995

crdoc.speakers
#=> ["Mr. DASCHLE", "The ACTING PRESIDENT pro tempore", "Mr. DOLE"]

crdoc.speakers.each do |speaker|
  speech = crdoc.speaking_parts(speaker)
  #save speech to file
end
```

This hides the details, making it much easier to read. Better yet, it would compartmentalize them so if the way you retrieve the speaker list changes, for example, you only have to change one small part, and that part will be easy to test. Let's implement it:

```
class CongressionalRecordDocument

  def initialize(xml_file)
    @doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml_file)
  end

  def year
    @year ||= @doc.at('//year')
  end

  def speakers
    @speakers ||= @doc.xpath('//speaker/@name').map(&:text).uniq
  end

  def speaking_parts(speaker)
    @doc.xpath("//speaking[@name = '#{speaker}']").map(&:text)
  end
end
```

Looks a lot less complex now, doesn't it? You may also want to create a class for your *new* document in a similar way so creating your output is as simple.

Also, instead of a `find -exec` you may want to find your files in ruby:

```
Dir["/path/to/search/*.xml"].each do |file|
  crdoc = CongressionalRecordDocument.new(file)
  #etc
end
```

Comment: This is a lot more comfortable and familiar to me. I appreciate the input. I will try this solution as soon as possible.

Comment: This is a most excellent explanation and starting point to build an intuitive parser. I am torn between who to award the answer.